# What is the probability that Person A will be chosen last every time$?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> There are $14$ people in a pool of subjects. People are selected at
>   random one at a time. All people are chosen and then Person A.(Person
>   A is chosen last every time  This trial occurs $3$ times).  What is the
>   probability that Person A will be chosen last every time.

---

My attempt:

I believe that it will be $(1/14)^{3}$ or $1$ in $2744$, but this does not seem to be as large as I thought it would be.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear IMO. First of all, if "All people are chosen except Person A", then "the probability that Person A will be chosen" is $0$. Second, what do you mean by "last ever time"???

Comment: Sorry, I meant that Person A will be chosen last in every trial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of ways to arrange $14$ people is $14!$.

The number of ways to arrange $14$ people with a specific person last is $13!$.

So in a single experiment, the probability of that person being chosen last is $\frac{13!}{14!}=\frac{1}{14}$.

Hence in $3$ experiments, the probability of that person being chosen last every time is $\left(\frac{1}{14}\right)^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your work appears to be correct. The probability would be: $$(1-\frac{13}{14})^{3}=(\frac{1}{14})^3$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **symmetry**, which avoids or lessens computations wherever applicable.

$A$ is equally likely to be chosen at **any** position, hence P($A$ at last position) $= \frac1{14}$

and P($A$ at last position thrice consecutively) $= (\frac1{14})^3$